# Aggregation output to Nest Arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset of records stored in mongodb and i have been trying to extract a complex set of data from the records.

Sample records are as follows :-

```
{
    bookId : '135wfkjdbv',
    type : 'a',
    store : 'crossword',
    shelf : 'A1'
}
{
    bookId : '13erjfn',
    type : 'b',
    store : 'crossword',
    shelf : 'A2'
}
```

I have been trying to extract data such that for each bookId, i get a count (of records) for each shelf per store name that holds the book identified by bookId where the type of the book is 'a'.

I understand that the aggregation query allows a pipeline that allows grouping, matching etc, but I have not been able to reach a solution.

The desired output is of the form :-

```
{
   bookId : '135wfkjdbv',
   stores : [
       {
           name : 'crossword'
           shelves : [
                {
                     name : 'A1',
                     count : 12
                },
           ]
       },
       {
           name : 'granth'
           shelves : [
                {
                     name : 'C2',
                     count : 12
                },
                {
                     name : 'C4',
                     count : 12
                },
           ]
       }  
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process isn't really that difficult when you look at at. The aggregation "pipeline" is exactly that, where each "stage" feeds a result into the next for processing. Just like unix "pipe":

```js
ps -ef | grep mongo | tee out.txt
```

So it's just adding stages, and in fact three [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages where the first does the basic aggregation and the remaining two simply "roll up" the arrays required in the output.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "bookId": "$bookId",
            "store": "$store",
            "shelf": "$shelf"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "bookId": "$_id.bookId",
            "store": "$_id.store"
        },
        "shelves": { 
            "$push": {
                "name": "$_id.shelf",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.bookId",
        "stores": {
            "$push": {
                "name": "$_id.store",
                "shelves": "$shelves"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

You could possibly `$project` at the end to change the `_id` to `bookId`, but you should already know that is what it is and get used to treating `_id` as a primary key. There is a cost to such operations, so it is a habit you should not get into and learn doing things correctly from the start.

So all that really happens here is all the fields that would make up the grouping detail are made the primary key of `$group` with the other field being produced as `count`, to count the shelves within that grouping. Think the SQL equivalent:

```js
GROUP BY bookId, store, shelf
```

All each other stage does is transpose each grouping level into array entries, first by shelf within the store and then the store within the bookId. Each time the fields in the primary grouping key are reduced down by the content going into the produced array.

When you start thinking in terms of "pipeline" processing, then it becomes clear. As you construct one form, then take that output and move it to the next form and so on. This is basically how you fold the results within two arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :)